# How to apply a hidden / remote sourcemap in Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, remote-debugging, source-maps, safari-web-inspector

I'm attempting to debug an issue in my react app, that's only occurring on iOS, in production.  I want to utilise a hidden sourcemap so I can debug the app's minified assets in Safari without overtly publishing the commented source.

> `hidden-source-map` - Same as source-map, but doesn’t add a reference comment to the bundle.
>
> https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool

In Chrome I can:

- serve the sourcemap wherever I like (eg `main.js.map` right next to the minified file)
- open the minified asset in the Sources tab
- right click and 'Add Sourcemap…', supplying the URL to main.js.map
- Cmd-p to select a source file (eg MyComponent.js)
- add breakpoints in the sourcemap
- profit (have the live app pause at the correct point)

I've searched, clicked, right clicked, examined the Safari devtools carefully, read what [Safari docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/ResourcesandtheDOM/ResourcesandtheDOM.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH3-SW4) I could find, to no avail...  the most relevant link I could find was:

> In Safari 7, Source Maps are not something that you have to toggle on or off they are just always on like resources are always available in the web developer tool.
>   [How do I toggle source mapping in Safari 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19550060/how-do-i-toggle-source-mapping-in-safari-7)

Is this possible in Safari?  Are there other approaches which might achieve a similar outcome in Safari?

Is there some tricky way to use a proxy to serve my local, unminified source to my testing iphone? (eg [assets-swapper-chrome-extension](https://github.com/maestr0/assets-swapper-chrome-extension). I have some sense that this might be possible, but have no idea how to do it!)

I'm on OSX 10.12, Safari 10.0.2.

---

Please note, this question is about using source-maps in Safari, which is not addressed in the question: [iPhone: add entry to /etc/hosts without jailbreaking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473939/iphone-add-entry-to-etc-hosts-without-jailbreaking)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone: add entry to /etc/hosts without jailbreaking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473939/iphone-add-entry-to-etc-hosts-without-jailbreaking)

Comment: thanks for reading @PaulSweatte, but that question doesn't relate to source-maps :)

Comment: Not directly, but by using the hosts file, your local domain can become the [destination of the remote domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138529/accessing-clients-localhost-from-javascript-online/1138614#1138614).

Comment: Thanks Paul, that would make the beginning of a helpful answer to the secondary question *'are there other approaches which might achieve a similar outcome'*, but marking the question as a possible duplicate is grounds for locking the question, which would be unfortunate, as a solution to the titular question would be valuable to me.

Comment: I've taken care of that, and in regards to the titular question, hopefully someone else can provide more insight.

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: I'm wondering if you ever found a solution to this because I am in the same situation. If you did, could you please post it here?

Comment: Sorry, moved on from it `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` maybe Safari has started supporting it since?